# Concurrent access to List

Tags: java, multithreading, libgdx, concurrent-programming

I'm trying to make a "Zelda-like" game in Java with Libgdx. As it will be lot of other things that my player, i'm trying to use Threads (example : for ennemies).
However, I have an exception and I don't find the solution :

> Exception in thread "Tort 1" Exception in thread "Tort 2" >com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: #iterator() cannot be used nested.
>     at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Array$ArrayIterator.hasNext(Array.java:523)
>     at com.defel.game.entite.ennemi.Ennemi.deplacementAleatoire(Ennemi.java:368)
>     at com.defel.game.entite.ennemi.Ennemi.run(Ennemi.java:234)

And the code which is concerned is :

```
private synchronized void deplacementAleatoire(){
    animationCourante = animationMarche[direction];

    boolean bloquer = false;

    for (MapObject obj : InfosSingleton.getInstance().getCollisionObjects()) {
        RectangleMapObject rectMapObject = (RectangleMapObject) obj;
        Rectangle rectObject = rectMapObject.getRectangle();

        if(Intersector.overlaps(rectObject, rectangleColl)){
            bloquer = true;
        }
    }

    if(bloquer){
        switch (direction) {
        case 0:
            direction = 2;
            break;
        case 1:
            direction = 3;
            break;
        case 2:
            direction = 0;
            break;
        case 3:
            direction = 1;
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
    } 

    switch (direction) {
    case 0:
        rectangle.setY(rectangle.getY() + 2);
        rectangleColl.setY(rectangleColl.getY() + 2);
        break;
    case 1:
        rectangle.setX(rectangle.getX() - 2);
        rectangleColl.setX(rectangleColl.getX() - 2);
        break;
    case 2:
        rectangle.setY(rectangle.getY() - 2);
        rectangleColl.setY(rectangleColl.getY() - 2);
        break;
    case 3:
        rectangle.setX(rectangle.getX() + 2);
        rectangleColl.setX(rectangleColl.getX() + 2);
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

I think that my thread can't access to the List at the same time but I don't know how to resolve it...

Do you have an idea ? Thanks =D

Comment: The site is english only, no need to have post your question with french translation (pas besoin de poster en anglais puis en français, l'anglais suffit.)

Comment: The posted code doesn't match the posted exception, can you post the code for `Ennemi#deplacementAleatoire`

Comment: There are lots of results for "#iterator() cannot be used nested" in Google search results; do none of these give any clues?

Comment: It seems a problem of `com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Array` implementation.  It occurs in single thread.  See [here](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/76109/libgdx-iterator-cannot-be-used-nested).

Comment: We still don't know what line 368 of `Ennemi` is. Also the code for  `InfosSingleton` could help getting an answer. I think the issue is in `getCollisionObjects`

Comment: Thanks saka :) it's working :) but I don't understand why ^^'
RC : this method is just a getter of MapObjects.

Comment: Premature optimization?